# Procedure using a view doesn't return the correct Name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure that use a join with other table and another View,i did this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSearchClicStatus]


@iClic int = NULL

AS

SELECT
        SC.dtDateCreated,V.USER_NAME, SC.iEDV, SC.sComments, sDescription, SC.iStatus
    FROM
        T_STATUS_CLIC SC INNER JOIN T_STATUS S
            ON SC.iSTATUS = S.iSTATUS,
        T_STATUS_CLIC SCC  INNER JOIN V_EMPLOYEES_MANAGER V
        on  SCC.iEDV = V.USER_EDV

    WHERE
        SC.iClic = @iClic
    ORDER BY 
        SC.dtDateCreated



GO
```

The problem is in the column V.USER_NAME , i want this column to get the name of the person that by his EDV (This is the people ID),but if only getting the name of the last person in action,like this Screenshot

[image]

Its getting the name of the last person,in the line 8,but i want each line to have the name of the current EDV in the line,what i'm doing wrong?

---

Now i managed to make it work,i did this:

```
SELECT
        SC.dtDateCreated,(select USER_NAME from V_EMPLOYEES_MANAGER where USER_EDV = SC.iEDV) as User_name,
        SC.iEDV, SC.sComments, (select sDescription from T_STATUS where iStatus = SC.iStatus) as Status_Desc, SC.iStatus
    FROM
        T_STATUS_CLIC SC             
   WHERE        
         SC.iClic = 101025


    ORDER BY 
        SC.dtDateCreated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed that cross join...

```
SELECT
    SC.dtDateCreated,V.USER_NAME, SC.iEDV, SC.sComments, sDescription, SC.iStatus
FROM
    T_STATUS_CLIC SC 
    INNER JOIN T_STATUS S ON SC.iSTATUS = S.iSTATUS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN V_EMPLOYEES_MANAGER V on  SC.iEDV = V.USER_EDV

WHERE
    SC.iClic = @iClic
ORDER BY 
    SC.dtDateCreated
```

Comment: Now its only showing the last row,where the iStatus is 7

Comment: The V_EMPLOYEES_MANAGER is the same as V_Employees just different name,i use this view because i can't directly acess this table

Comment: changed it to a left outer join, I'd guess the employees table simply doesn't have those other USER_EDV values....

Comment: Didn't work also,in the employees table there is all those User_EDV values,but if there is more than one EDV in a CLIC,it only get the last one.